# Time Complexity of nested for loops with different conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity for this snippet? I'm having a little trouble understanding how to find the time complexity of nested for loops with different conditions.

I originally thought that it would be n^3 x n^2 which gives O(n^5), but should it be (n^3)^2 which gives O(n^6)?

```
for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n*n*n; j++) {
        A(); //O(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it be O(n^6)? In the inner loop you have `n*n*n*O(1)`. With the outer loop, you have `n*n` times the complexity of the loop body, i.e. the complexity of the inner loop: `(n*n)*(n*n*n*O(1))`. So your initial thought was correct.

Comment: Because of the `i++` in the inner loop, the complexity is O(n^2), presuming something else will terminate the inner loop.  Else, if nothing terminates the inner loop it is O(∞).

Comment: Haha, that's right. But I suppose that's a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly incremented `j` in the inner loop (replacing `i++` with `j++` in the inner loop increment step), it would be `O(n⁵)`. The outer loop runs the inner loop `n²` times, with each inner loop running `n³` times; the total is strictly multiplicative, `n² * n³ == n⁵`.

As written, it'll never stop running if `n > 1` (because `j` never increments, so if the inner loop begins running, it runs forever).